# AngularJS directive file upload with progress bar from AngularJS O'Reilly book

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm starting with angularjs and I am following the book o'reilly, angularJS. In there an example of using file upload File Upload blueImp.

I can upload files, but now I want to show a progress bar and I can not access the element that contains it during the "progress" event.

In the declaration of the directive have "element" from where I access the container element and once there, show div with the progress bar, but the progress event have no access to "element" (one is passed two arguments, e & data) so during the file upload I can not show the bar. I have looked at many examples but is used differently than what I'm doing so, so they do not serve me.

Is it possible to pass "element" to the function that runs on the progress event?

```
ecm_directives.directive('fileupload', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
       done: '&',
       progress: '&',
 },  
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var optionsObj = { 
       dataType: 'json'
 };  

 if (scope.done) {
    optionsObj.done = function(e, data) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.done({e: e, data: data});
      }); 
    };  
 }   

 if (scope.progress) {
    optionsObj.progress = function(e, data) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.progress({e: e, data: data});
      }); 
    };  
 }   

 //the above could easily be done in a loop, to cover
 //all API's that Fileupload provides
 element.fileupload(optionsObj);
 }   
 }
});
```

And this is the html

```
<div class="file-input-wrapper">

     <div class="progress-bar">
         <div class="bar"></div>
     </div>


    <button class="btn-file-input ng-binding">Subir</button>
    <input type="file" name="ccedulaCandidato" accept=".pdf, image/jpeg, image/png" data-url="/backend/documents/save/" fileupload="" 
         done="uploadFinishedGeneral(e, data)" 
         progress="uploadOnProgressGeneral(e, data)" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="candidateFiles.cedula.token" name="ccedulaCandidatoToken" value="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
</div>
```

And in generalCtrl

```
$scope.uploadOnProgressGeneral = function(e, data) {


  // In this point, i want to show progressbar but I cant access to
  // parent element from the input uploaded file

  elementParent = $(this).parents('.file-wrapper').parent();
  progressBar = elementParent.find('.progress-bar');
  bar = progressBar.find('.bar');
  bar.css('width', parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10) + '%');
  elementParent.removeClass('error').find('.restrictions').hide();

};
```